# Added Custom User Profile property sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile

I have create 2 custom User profile properties; but they are not reflecting in the editprofile.aspx in sharepoint Online. How much time does it take to reflect it in the edit page/ or do we have to do any more setting for them to appear. There are also sections on the MgrProperty.aspx page. How to add the custom property to the section so they can show up in editprofile.aspx

[image]

Comment: Let me know which SharPoint version you are using?

Comment: Sharepoint Online 365 2013

Comment: are the values populated ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.Actually in our code itself we were hiding the field. That i realize later on. And overrode the code..Thank you for all your valuable inputs

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, you must be have an idea how the managed properties taking a part in the user profile.

Here are the steps

1. Create the managed properties
2. Map the created managed properties with crawl properties.
3. The associated crawled properties must have a data exist.
4. Wait for the crawl to complete. (As office 365 you have not much control over the crawl)
5. You need to update the search people display template and add the created managed properties at the top of the section please check this template (https://www.eliostruyf.com/important-managed-properties-for-rendering-people-results/)

> Troubleshoot: download the query tool
>   https://sp2013searchtool.codeplex.com/ from this link and check
>   managed properties values. This helps you to debug the template.